# Multiplayer variants with Google Game services

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm trying to set up a game which has many types, and each types has many sizes and each sizes has many difficult levels. But the RoomConfig Build states:

`public RoomConfig.Builder setVariant (int variant)`

Sets the variant for the room when calling createRoom(RoomConfig). This is an optional, developer-controlled parameter describing the type of game to play, and is used for auto-matching criteria. Must be either a value from 1 to 1023 (inclusive), or ROOM_VARIANT_ANY (the default) if not desired.

I can't split all these types up in an integer from 1 to 1023, even if I split them on bits on that integer.

So is there a way to send more than one parameter to the game creation?

Comment: How many variations do you actually have?  (types * sizes * difficulty levels)

Comment: I have a lot. And I actually have subtypes too.

Comment: He's now saying he has 50,000 variations. It would have been helpful if he had said that in the first place !

Comment: I don't say I have 50000 variations. I gave you that number so you could understand that I actually know how to divide things in bits. Didn't I say in the question that 1023 wasn't enough? Does it matter how many above I need?

Comment: You said you had 50,000 variations in response to my answer. Now you say you do not. Your original question was not clear. You are not communicating well, and when people try and help you, you just rubbish their efforts.

Comment: I'm sorry @IanB, but you should learn to read. Where did I say in the first place that I had under 1023 variants, which is a criteria for your solution. And where did I actually say I had 50000 variants? What did I write? Stop being mad because your wrong answer was voted down.

Comment: "I can't split all these types up in an integer from 1 to 1023, even if I split them on bits on that integer" is neither clear nor grammatically correct. My initial response was clearly based on a misunderstanding. Rather than trying to score points, you could simply have pointed that out. This is an English-language site, and most native-speakers will always try to make allowances for those with a poor command of English. However, it is bad etiquette to rubbish the efforts of people who are trying to help you, especially when your own poor communication is the problem. I accept your apology.

Comment: Can you tell me how you read that line? I'm eager to understand how that line can be understood in a way that splitting the variants on bits would be a valid solution. Btw, you know I loose points when I vote down an answer? I didn't vote it down to be mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33095/discussion-between-flogvit-and-ianb)

Answer (score 8):

No, we currently only support the values 1 through 1023 for variant. Remember that every time you use a variant, you are cutting down on the size of your random player pool. The more variants your game has, the less likely it will be that, at any given time, automatching will find a match to play with you. So if you have 1024 variants, you'd need thousands and thousands of users online at the same time to make it reasonably likely that a particular player would find a match at any given time.

The recommendation in this case is to compromise a little bit. Use the variant only to select the major game type, and then negotiate in-game to determine what minor variation will be played. I don't know the specifics of your game, but I think most players wouldn't mind playing something that's a little different than they expected, if the other option is waiting for all eternity until someone decides to pick that exact variant they want to play.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but based on what you are saying it's a 10 bit field and you can use all the values except 0 .

So, for example, you could divide the 10 bits up into group of 3, 3 and 4:

type (e.g. 0b111) , size (e.g. 0b001), difficulty level (e.g. 0b1111)  or in groups of bits in whatever way you want.

It seems like straightforward (albeit old school) programming to me. There again, I haven't tried it !

Comment: The allowable values are between 1 and 1023, so there are only 10 bits available, not 32.

Comment: Sorry you are correct !- but the same principle applies. You can use 3 bits for one thing, 3 for another - 4 for something else my answer updated

Comment: As I said, I can't split them into bits. It's not enough values.

Comment: Yes you can ! You have 10 bits and you can allocate them however you want. Re-read my answer, and if you don't understand binary just work in decimal instead - the same principle applies.

Comment: @IanB I don't have enough. Show me how to use those 10 bits to create a number which will cover 50000 different variations. That's why I did ask the question in the first place, because I don't have enough bits as in "even if I split them on bits".

Comment: Why didnt you say that in your question then ? You did not say anything about 50,000 different variations.